# pattern in pgfgantt's ganttbars?

Tags: pgfgantt

Is it possible to specify `pattern` in a `ganttbar` in any way? The following

```
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{2}
        \ganttbar[pattern=north west lines]{Some bar}{1}{2} \\
\end{ganttchart}
```

gives

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfgantt/pattern' and I am goi
ng to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Apparently it's not implemented. Is it possible in any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the current `bar`'s style and `append` the pattern specification to it.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{5}
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={pattern=north west lines}]{Some bar}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Another bar}{2}{5}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is very weird: This indeed works when compiled with `pdflatex` but doesn't work when compiled with `xelatex`. The bar that should be patterned is empty. There is no error message in the log. What might be the issue?

Comment: Is your installation up-to-date? There used to be problems with XeLaTeX and patterns but I think they have been resolved. I just tested with `xelatex` on my system and it shows the pattern as expected. On my (working) system: XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3; `pgfgantt`, v4.0 (2013-06-01); `tikz`, v3.0.0 (2013-12-13, rcs-revision 1.142).

Comment: My `tikz.sty` is 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76). Everything else is the same version as you. I'll check it out with a newer version.

Comment: Any news? Did it work with updated `tikz`/`pgf`?