# pattern for pgfgantt ganttchartelements

Tags: pgfgantt, pattern

I like to add a shading pattern for black and white printing to the foobar elements of this example code from the pgfgantt manual.

```
\documentclass[a2paper, 10pt, parskip=full, listof=toc,  bibliography=numbered, draft=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{foobarblue}{RGB}{0,153,255}
\definecolor{foobaryellow}{RGB}{234,187,0}
\newganttchartelement{foobar}{
        foobar/.style={
                shape=rounded rectangle,
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=foobarblue!50!black,
                very thick,
                top color=white,
                bottom color=foobarblue!50
        },
        foobar incomplete/.style={
                /pgfgantt/foobar,
                draw=foobaryellow,
                bottom color=foobaryellow!50
        },
        foobar label font=\slshape,
        foobar left shift=-.1,
        foobar right shift=.1
}
\begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid,
        progress=today,
        progress label text=\relax,
        today=6
]{1}{12}
\gantttitlecalendar{day} \\[grid]
\ganttfoobar{Foobar 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttfoobar{Foobar 2}{3}{7} \\
\ganttlinkedfoobar{Foobar 3}{9}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

In this question
[pattern in pgfgantt's ganttbars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/pattern-in-pgfgantts-ganttbars/188142) it is explained how to do it to a single entry, but since I have lots of entries, I would prefer to add it to the newganttchartelement definition, but I haven't found a way to do so. Is this possible at all? And if so, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is not really much different from the question you refer to actually, i.e. add e.g. `pattern=north east lines` to the `foobar` style. The only problem is that the filling covers over the pattern, but if you set `fill opacity=0.5` the pattern becomes visible through the fill.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a2paper, 10pt, parskip=full, listof=toc,  bibliography=numbered, draft=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{foobarblue}{RGB}{0,153,255}
\definecolor{foobaryellow}{RGB}{234,187,0}
\newganttchartelement{foobar}{
        foobar/.style={
                shape=rounded rectangle,
                inner sep=0pt,
                draw=foobarblue!50!black,
                very thick,
                top color=white,
                bottom color=foobarblue,
                fill opacity=0.5,
                pattern=north west lines
        },
        foobar incomplete/.style={
                /pgfgantt/foobar,
                draw=foobaryellow,
                bottom color=foobaryellow,
                pattern=north east lines
        },
        foobar label font=\slshape,
        foobar left shift=-.1,
        foobar right shift=.1
}
\begin{ganttchart}[
        vgrid,
        progress=today,
        progress label text=\relax,
        today=6
]{1}{12}
\gantttitlecalendar{day} \\[grid]
\ganttfoobar{Foobar 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttfoobar{Foobar 2}{3}{7} \\
\ganttlinkedfoobar{Foobar 3}{9}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```